# How to convert NA's in a large dataset to either 0 or 1?

Tags: r, function, binary, dataset

Here is a snippet of my data frame:

```
MemberID      Specialty                   Surgery          Internal
1 42286978     Surgery                      NA               NA
2 97903248     Internal                     NA               NA
3 2759427      Internal                     NA               NA      
4 73570559     Surgery                      NA               NA
```

Under the columns Surgery and Internal I would like to replace the NA's with either 0 or 1, 1 being yes and 0 being no. It is a very large data set and I would prefer to use a tool or a function within r to do this.

The table below is what I hope to achieve.

```
    MemberID    Specialty                 Surgery          Internal
1  42286978     Surgery                      1                0
2  97903248     Internal                     0                1
3   2759427     Internal                     0                1  
4  73570559     Surgery                      1                0
```

I would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your dataframe is named `dfrm`, do you mean something like that?

```
dfrm$Surgery <- ifelse(dfrm$Specialty=="Surgery", 1, 0)
dfrm$Internal <- ifelse(dfrm$Specialty=="Internal", 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 4):

Presume that this a dataframe named dfrm

```
dfrm$Surgery <- 0 + (dfrm$Specialty=="Surgery")
dfrm$Internal <- 0 + (dfrm$Specialty=="Internal")
```

Comment: I have a mild preference for `as.numeric(x)` to the computer-science-tricky `0+x` to coerce to numeric ... I think something involving `model.matrix(~Specialty-1,data=dfrm)` might work too (it would be much more worthwhile with more categories)

Comment: Maybe we should define an `%0/1%` dyadic function in our workspaces?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest starting with `MemberID` and `Specialty` alone, and using some `ifelse` language.

If Surgery and Internal are mutually exclusive, you only need one new variable because the second one gives you the exact same information (whether a doctor is a surgeon or practices internal medicine).

Make your data a `data.frame` called *specialty.data*, and try this:

```
specialty.data$Surgery <- ifelse( specialty.data$Specialty == "Surgery", 1, 0 )
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is this really any different than chl's answer?

Comment: This works very well, Thank you, There are many variables that i need to incorporate with this method